# How to check file extension while uploading a file in multifile.js

Tags: javascript, multifile-uploader

I need to upload DOC and XLS files to my application. I'm using [**multifile.js**](http://multifile.frantatoman.cz/) for uploading the file.

I need to **prevent uploading** files except DOC and XLS - how can i achieve that?

Comment: perhaps if you included a link to the plugin you're using, that would help... also, I wouldn't depend on client-side verification alone here, since anyone can rename an EXE file into XSL and send it anyway

Comment: @ZathrusWriter The plugin I'm using in my project is  http://multifile.frantatoman.cz/#header-overview

Answer (score 4):

This script should be put as a validation before file is submitted. It should also work for filenames which already contains '.'(dot) eg.. myfile.ms.xls etc...

```
var splitLength = parseInt($('#file').val().split('.').length)
var extensionCaseInsensitive = $('#file').val().split('.')[splitLength-1]    

if (extensionCaseInsensitive.toUpperCase() == 'DOC' || extensionCaseInsensitive.toUpperCase() == 'XLS') {
    // allow upload
}
```

But remember one thing if a user is literally naming a png image as doc file then we cannot check the contents to validate or probably it will a much longer and complicated exercise.

Comment: just a little note - this would not work with uppercase file extensions, otherwise it seems legit :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter thanks for pointing it out... I will do the change accordingly.

Comment: Just a typo I guess, but "[length-1]" on the second line needs to be "[splitLength-1]'. Other than that, I'm using this now :).

Comment: @smets.kevin thanks for pointing out... I did the edit accordingly.